# Privilégio de downvote sem os pontos necessários

Tags: bug, status-intencional

Já tem uns dias que recebi o privilégio de *DownVote*, conforme pode ser visto abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas, para obter esse privilégio, são necessários 125 pontos, mas eu só tenho 121.

Procurei para ver se recebi algum *downvote*, mas não localizei e acredito que não haja.

Então, seria esse um bug, ou é alguma coisa que aconteceu e eu não visualizei?

Comment: Talvez você tenha ganho um upvote que foi retirado em menos de 5 minutos, e nesse meio tempo você ganhou o privilégio. Você consegue votar contra? Provavelmente não.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não consigo. Até tentei para ver se seria possível, mas não deu. Inclusive, na página de privilégios, exibe que faltam 4 pontos para obter esse privilégio. Provavelmente foi isso. Vlw!

Comment: Bueno, já tens o privilégio de volta, *use it wisely* ;)

Comment: @bfavaretto, mas retirar um up não computa negativo?

Comment: @PapaCharlie Retirando dentro dos 5 minutos iniciais, acho que só remove o positivo, sem computar negativo.

Comment: Perguntei pois em duas ocasioes sumiram 2 pontos sem computar - ate ia postar aqui, mas deixei de lado. Obs, foram 2 pontos, talvez uma edicao desfeita?

Answer (score 2):

Aconteceu exatamente o que o @bfavaretto disse. Você recebeu um voto que te passou dos 125 pontos e que foi removido 1min depois. Ficou só o registro de que você tinha ultrapassado a barreira dos 125.